# $x \in y \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}(x) \in \mathcal{P}(y)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

my 
doubt is if

$$x \in y \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}(x) \in \mathcal{P}(y)$$
is true,
where $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the power set of A: $\mathcal{P}(A)= \{T| T \subseteq A\}$.

Comment: Just in case this is a homework exercise, please be mindful that stackexchange is not here to do your homework. If you have trouble with a problem, it is good form to provide your own attempt at solving it first and then ask for hints, rather than asking for a full solution.

If this is not homework, please ignore what I said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $x=\{\emptyset\}$ and $y=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$. We have $x \in y$ and the following:
$$\mathcal P(x)=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$$
$$\mathcal P(y)=\{\emptyset, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$$
Clearly, $\mathcal P(x) \notin \mathcal P(y)$, so your statement is false.

Comment: This is a very elegant response, probably the most elegant possible for the given question. Now this got me thinking about situations in which $\mathcal{P}(x)$ truly is in $\mathcal{P}(y)$, with $x$ in $y$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

The statement $\mathcal{P}(x)\in\mathcal{P}(y)$ means that $\mathcal{P}(x)\subseteq y$, in other words that every subset of $x$ belongs to $y$.

Thus you get a counterexample by finding $x\in y$ such that no subset of $x$ belongs to $y$: simply define $y=\{x\}$. The condition that all subsets of $x$ belong to $y$ becomes “every subset of $x$ is equal to $x$”, which only holds for $x=\emptyset$.